# If f is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$, there is a $c$ such that $f'(c) = 0$

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity, contest-math

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$$

How can I prove that there exists at least a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x) = 0$. It reminds of Rolle's Theorem, but, instead of having 2 points where the function is the same, we have the limits. Intuitively, it makes sense, but I am looking for a mathematical proof.

Also, I don't know if it's true or not. I am using it for solving another problem and this property would prove very useful, were it real.

Comment: use epsilon-delta definition from the limits to prove the existence of a value $x_1$ where $f(x_1)<0$ and a $x_2$ where $f(x_2)>0$.

Comment: for example, for M<0, there exists some $\delta$ such that for any x with $|x-d|<0$ we have that $f(x)< M$. lets take $x_1$ on that interval. ...

Comment: $f$ has to be a differentiable function, not just continuous. Else $f(x) = -|x|$ is a counter example

Answer (score 3):

Note that if $f$ is not differentiable (even at just one point), this is not true as illustrated by $f(x) = -|x|$.

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. 
That means $f$ is also continuous.  
Because of continuity and the given limits, for any arbitrary $z$, the function attains the value $A = f(z)-1$ at least once at $q < z$ and at least once at $r > z$ s.t. $f(q)=f(r)=A$. 
Then,  $\exists c \in [q, z]$, by Rolle's theorem such that $f'(c)=0$. 
Also note that we couldn't have applied Rolle's theorem without differentiability.

### Why such a $q$ must exist?

We already have $z$ s.t. $f(z)=A+1$.

The definition of the limit being $- \infty$ at $- \infty$ is that, 
for all $M < 0$, there exists a $N$, such that 
$f(x) < M$ for all $x <N$

Here, take $M=A-1$. Then, there exists a $N$ such that $f(x)<A-1$ for all $x < z < N$

That, is for some $s <z$, we have $f(s)<A-1$

Let $f(s)=A-1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ (by definition of $<$)

Consider the interval $[s, z]$. 
$f(s)=A-1-\epsilon$ and $f(z)=A+1$.
$A  \in [f(s), f(z)]$.

Now we can apply the IVT to obtain existence of $q<z$ s.t. $f(q)=A$

Comment: Thank you! But could you please prove more rigorously that $f(z) - 1$ is attained at least onced on both intervals?

Comment: @andueu  I have added that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=f(0)$. By hypothesis, it exists $b \lt 0$ and $c \gt 0$ such that for $x \notin (b,c)$, we have $f(x) \lt A -1$.

On the interval $[b,c]$, $f$ attains its maximum at an interior point where the derivative vanishes, providing that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$.